# Maatwebsite Laravel Excel import

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import, maatwebsite-excel

I use code below for import all models at the same time from different excel files.
It works well on Laravel 7.
But when I move it to Laravel 8, I always get error `PDOException There is no active transaction` 
I see in DB that only one import of News model is done.
I cannot understand the reason of this problem. Documentation seems the same and there is no help in guthub.

**App\Admin\routes.php**

```
$router->get('seed', 'SeedController@index')->name('admin.seed');
```

**App\Admin\Controllers\SeedController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Imports\Feedback\FeedbackImport;
use App\Imports\News\NewsImport;
use App\Imports\Menu\MenuImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class SeedController extends BaseAdminController
{
    public $feedback;
    public $news;
    public $menu;

    public function __construct()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
        $this->feedback = new FeedbackImport();
        $this->news = new NewsImport();
        $this->menu = new MenuImport();
    }

    public function index(Content $content)
    {
        $this->import();
        $feedback = $this->feedback;
        $news = $this->news;
        $menu = $this->menu;
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');

        return $content
            ->title('Import & Export')
            ->description('Laravel excel')
            ->view('admin.seed', compact('menu', 'news', 'feedback'))
            ->withSuccess('Import succesfully finished');
    }

    public function import()
    {
        Excel::import($this->feedback, 'import/feedback.xlsm');
        Excel::import($this->news, 'import/news.xlsm');
        Excel::import($this->menu, 'import/menu.xlsm');
    }

}
```

**App\Imports\Feedback\FeedbackImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports\Feedback;

use App\Models\Feedback;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class FeedbackImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow,  WithEvents

{
    use RegistersEventListeners;
    public $rows = 0;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        ++$this->rows;
        return new Feedback([
                 'name'         => $row['name'],
                 'rate'         => $row['rate'],
                 'text'         => $row['text'],
        ]);
    }

    public function getRowCount(): int
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    public static function beforeSheet(BeforeSheet $event)
    {
        app('log')->info('Feedback import started');
        Feedback::truncate();       
    }

    public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
    {
        app('log')->info('Feedback import finished');
    }

}
```

**App\Imports\News\NewsImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports\News;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterImport;

class NewsImport implements WithMultipleSheets, WithEvents

{
    use RegistersEventListeners;

    public $category;
    public $post;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->category = new NewsImportCategory();
        $this->post = new NewsImportPost();
    }

    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'news_categories'   => $this->category,
            'news_posts'        => $this->post,
        ];
    }

    public static function beforeImport(BeforeImport $event)
    {
        app('log')->info('News import started');
    }

    public static function afterImport(AfterImport $event)
    {
        app('log')->info('News import finished');
    }

}
```

**App\Imports\News\NewsImportCategory.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports\News;

use App\Models\NewsCategory;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class NewsImportCategory implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithEvents

{
    use RegistersEventListeners;
    public $rows = 0;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        if (empty($row['id'])) { return null; }

        ++$this->rows;
 
        return new NewsCategory([
                 'id'           => $row['id'],
                 'parent_id'    => $row['parent_id'],
                 'title'        => $row['title'],
                 'description'  => $row['description'],
        ]);
    }
    
    
    public function getRowCount(): int
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }


    public static function beforeSheet(BeforeSheet $event)
    {
        app('log')->info('NewsCategory import started');
        NewsCategory::truncate();
    }


    public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
    {
        app('log')->info('NewsCategory import finished');
    }


}
```

**App\Imports\News\NewsImportPost.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports\News;

use App\Models\NewsPost;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class NewsImportPost implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithEvents

{
    use RegistersEventListeners;
    public $rows = 0;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        if (empty($row['category_id'])) { return null; }

        ++$this->rows;
        return new NewsPost([
                 'category_id'  => $row['category_id'],
                 'title'        => $row['title'],
                 'fulltext'     => $row['fulltext'],
                 'image'        => $row['image'],
        ]);
    }
        
    public function getRowCount(): int
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    public static function beforeSheet(BeforeSheet $event)
    {
        app('log')->info('NewsPost import started');
        NewsPost::truncate();
    }

    public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
    {
        app('log')->info('NewsPost import finished');
    }

}
```

Menu is almost same as News import.